# call back function not working in angular js?

Tags: php, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I am trying to update a product using angular function. Product is added successfully. Inside success function I am calling other function. So for its fine. Inside the second function I am trying to fetch records from database. But it is not happening. Server side scripting language is PHP. Below is my coding:

```
var listApp = angular.module('listApp', []);
     listApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.title= 'I am Excited';


    $scope.product_submit = function() {
        $http.post('db.php?action=add_product',
            {
                'prod_name'     : $scope.prod_name,
                'prod_desc'     : $scope.prod_desc,
                'prod_price'    : $scope.prod_price,
                'prod_quantity' : $scope.prod_quantity
            }
        )
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          alert("Product has been Submitted Successfully");
          $scope.get_product();

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
          alert("Unable to update");
        });
    }


    $scope.get_product = function() {
        console.log('Block 1');
        $http.get("db.php?action=get_products").success(function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            //$scope.product_detail = data;  
            //$scope.pagedItems = data;    

        });
    }


});
```

in the above method inside success method I am calling get_product(). inside the second method I added console.log('Success'). So for it is working fine. After that it is not sending any request to server? Please advice.

Thanks to: http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/perform-addeditdeleteview-php-using-angular-js

Comment: Is it definitely not sending the request to the server, or is it possible that the request is failing so your success handler isn't being called? (you could try adding an error handler to your call within get_product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies.. I found the solution. I define the method above it is working Fine. It means that any method should be defined above the place where it is being called.. Since I am new to angular js unaware of it.

```
$scope.get_product = function() {
        console.log('Block 1');
        $http.get("db.php?action=get_products").success(function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            //$scope.product_detail = data;  
            //$scope.pagedItems = data;    

        });
    }


     $scope.product_submit = function() {
        $http.post('db.php?action=add_product',
            {
                'prod_name'     : $scope.prod_name,
                'prod_desc'     : $scope.prod_desc,
                'prod_price'    : $scope.prod_price,
                'prod_quantity' : $scope.prod_quantity
            }
        )
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          alert("Product has been Submitted Successfully");
          $scope.get_product();

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
          alert("Unable to update");
        });
    }
```

Comment: That's a general JavaScript feature, not just Angular related - read about function hoisting. Though I'm not sure how would the POST success callback get executed before the script it was called from... Nice catch anyway.